# Updating server-side variable in Vaadin6 using GWT widget

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

I am implementing GWT Widget (using Vaadin 6) to implement google wallet in my web app using wallet Javascript Library. Actually I have an issue regarding **`ApplicationConnection.updateVariable()`** method, I want to update my variable at server-side whenever I got the result from Javascript (whenever google's payment API calls a confirmation method in my script).
When I received the confirmation from google, I call my widget's

**`client.updateVariable(paintableId, "paymentStatus", paymentStatus, true);`**(paymentStatus is a string)

with immediate parameter **true**.

The problem I am facing is that after completing one cycle of purchase and then  calling the above method my server-side method  **`changeVariables()`** didn't get triggered, unless I click any other component or do somthing which makes a server call or again hit the wallet button.

I was expecting that after calling the above mentioned method I got into the server-side component ,I set a breakpoint at **`CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest()`** which is not triggered after **`updateVariable()`** call.

May be I am not getting the way the **`updateVariable()`** method works. Any explanation regarding this method or any way out to this issue is appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Henri

[thread](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/4652228)

using DevMode I figure out that the variable I was sending (i.e. paymentStatus) found to be null and hence thrown into the NullPointerException rather going into server-side code